# Route function removes all displayed items in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router-dom

I have a react js project that I am working on and whenever I put this code (that is neccessary for my website):

```
<Route path='/contractor/:id' component={ContactorInfoScreen}/>
<Route path='/' exact={true} component={HomeScreen}/>
```

all the text, images etc. all disapear from my page.
I have made sure that I have imported all the neccessary items from the correct file paths.
These are the things that I have imported:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import data from './data';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ContractorInfoScreen from './screens/ContractorInfoScreen';
```

Is there possibly another item that I need to import that I have not already done so?

Comment: Other than the possible typo with the `ContractorInfoScreen` component name I don't see any overt issue here. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I noticed something in the code you posted on Github...The components HomeScreen and ProductScreen have a typo as well ... They have at the top "import react from 'react';" ... it should instead be "import React from 'react';"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. I needed to run this in the terminal:

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

I already had react-router-dom installed, just not the most recent revision.

Thanks for all the help that anyone has given. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in the name of the component ContractorInfoScreen in your Html...

This

```
<Route path='/contractor/:id' component={ContactorInfoScreen}/>
```

should be

```
<Route path='/contractor/:id' component={ContractorInfoScreen}/>
```

Comment: thanks for that i realised after i posted this question. but even after fixing that typo it still doesnt work

Comment: I noticed something in the code you posted on Github...The components HomeScreen and ProductScreen have a typo as well ... They have at the top "import react from 'react';" ... it should instead be "import React from 'react';"

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found the solution... I had an outdated version of react-router-dom installed.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo mistake on `component={ContractorInfoScreen}`

Comment: thanks for that i realised after i posted this question. but even after fixing that typo it still doesnt work

Comment: Can you share the source code?

Comment: i will post it onto github and post the link here when it uploads. my internet is extremely slow so it will take a few minutes

Comment: you can just copy and paste here also with file names(if they are a few)

Comment: https://github.com/LukeCripps/JSError

Comment: Stack Overflow was saying that there was too many characters to post so i just uploaded the files to github

Comment: files on github are not the last changes, I guess. they are different from your question code

Comment: yes i changed the name of the item to see if that would help with anything

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found the solution... I had an outdated version of react-router-dom installed.